# How to update a table from a FUNCTION or SPROC and / or Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I dont code a lot of years and i need help, pls.

I need to update a table where happens "somethings", that's why i need to
call a "function/procedure" where i can pass the parameters, where "those
things" will happen. I know... what a mess... with example:

```
BEGIN

UPDATE tab_or
SET [1] = (CASE WHEN ([1] IS NULL) THEN @aux 
                WHEN ([1] NOT LIKE '%'+@aux+'%') THEN CONCAT([1], ' | ', @aux) 
                ELSE [1] END)
WHERE [2] = (SELECT [2] FROM tab_or WHERE row_id = @row);

END;
```

Because this (and another similar instructions will repeat a lot of times) > i need to call a function/procedure "or other kind of solution" where i can > give 2 parameters (the parameters will be the name of the fields, in this > case [1] and [2]).

Can anyone help me to code this? Im stuck in my work with a table of 255000 > lines... which cannot be crossed at hand... thats the reason i need this > code.

Comment: updates can only be made in procedures.  Functions process and return a value, procedures can update/delete/insert etc.

Comment: sorry i forgot, i need a procedure that do those instructions but where i can give the parameters (name of fields), something like: IF ' something' then CALL XPTO (1, 2)

Comment: ok xQbert, i understand that... but how can i code to create this procedure where those instructions (between BEGIN and END) will run and that when i call the procedure, i can give him the 2 parameters? thanks for your time

Comment: You can't use variables for table / column names. The only option is to make dynamic SQL. Be aware of SQL injection though.

Comment: Ok but can you help me with those Dynamic SQL code, pls?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your UpdateQuery into a VARCHAR and use EXEC (@UpdateQuery)

See sample:

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @1 VARCHAR(50)

SET @1 = 'Id'
SET @Test = 'SELECT ' + @1 + ' FROM table WHERE  LIKE ''%' + @param + '%'''

EXEC (@Test)
```